# Intersection of parameter sets in Revit-Api

Tags: ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I'm trying to explore Quick, Slow and LINQ filter in Revit API using Python. So I decided to create universal filter to any category by filtering parameters values or Family/Category/Symbol.

Now I have a set of elements of different categories (Walls, Floors, Family Symbols, ect) came from the FilteredElementCollector(document) and I need to get all parameters that are in any element in collection. In other words intersection of parameter sets. It would be perfect if it will be possible to make such filter without using LINQ

```
uidoc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = uidoc.Document

collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc)

list_of_categories = [
    ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns),
    ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls),
    ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_Floors)
]

logical_filter = LogicalOrFilter(list_of_categories)
collector.WherePasses(logical_filter)
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I can think of how you would build a custom class with a few loops to achieve this - but it would be neither elegant or fast, are you looking for something out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, it sounds to me more like a union of parameter sets than an intersection. You might want to check out the parameter analysis and handling functionality that I implemented for [RvtMetaProp](https://github.com/jeremytammik/rvtmetaprop), a Revit C# .NET add-in to import and store meta properties created in [Forge](https://autodesk-forge.github.io).